# Generate Code in R

Tags: r

Please help generate R code for the following. I'm new to R and I'm really interested in knowing more. I just need a little help.

*** AnnualIncome of Males is less than Females***

Dataframe = DF (has the following values)

Age         Gender         AnnualIncome       MaritalStatus

54          Female            109000             Single

22            Male             62541           Divorced

38            Male              93214           Married

42           Female            62471           Married

35           Female            98741            Single

42           Male              98741            Married

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a duplicate, but here you go:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Age Gender AnnualIncome MaritalStatus

54 Female 109000 Single

22 Male 62541 Divorced

38 Male 93214 Married

42 Female 62471 Married

35 Female 98741 Single

42 Male 98741 Married", header = TRUE)
```

Result:

```
> df
  Age Gender AnnualIncome MaritalStatus
1  54 Female       109000        Single
2  22   Male        62541      Divorced
3  38   Male        93214       Married
4  42 Female        62471       Married
5  35 Female        98741        Single
6  42   Male        98741       Married
```

Compare means per group (`df$Gender`) with:

```
aggregate(df$AnnualIncome, list(df$Gender), mean)

> aggregate(df$AnnualIncome, list(df$Gender), mean)
  Group.1        x
1  Female 90070.67
2    Male 84832.00
```